# Sourcetree can not open .tsx files

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

We have a project, which we share on github and we use Sourcetree to commit/update it to GitHub.

Oh yeah, we also use Intellij to develop this project.

On sourcetree, if I double click on .java files for example, it opens them on intellij, but if I double click on .tsx nothing happens.

Does anyone know how I can fix it? Super thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the system-wide default application used to open .tsx files with:

On macOS for instance, using Finder, find a .tsx file, or right click on of those files on sourcetree and choose show in finder.

- Right click on the file, choose Get Info
- Expand Open With and choose Intellij
- Click Change All...

Hope it helps.